# Magento 2 - new inscription newsletter error (no such entity with customerId = 0)

Tags: magento2, newsletter

I always have this error when I try to register to newsletter in Magento 2. The error is:

```
No such entity with customerId = 0
```

If I try to add it directly from database, it works perfectly.

Comment: Please add some code so we can see where the problem is happening

Answer (score 1):

The function is :

> vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

```
public function subscribe($email)
    {
        $this->loadByEmail($email);

        if (!$this->getId()) {
            $this->setSubscriberConfirmCode($this->randomSequence());
        }
        $isConfirmNeed = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_CONFIRMATION_FLAG,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        ) == 1 ? true : false;
        $isOwnSubscribes = false;
        $isSubscribeOwnEmail = $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()
            && $this->_customerSession->getCustomerDataObject()->getEmail() == $email;

        if (!$this->getId() || $this->getStatus() == self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED
            || $this->getStatus() == self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE
        ) {
            if ($isConfirmNeed === true) {
                // if user subscribes own login email - confirmation is not needed
                $isOwnSubscribes = $isSubscribeOwnEmail;
                if ($isOwnSubscribes == true) {
                    $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
                } else {
                    $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE);
                }
            } else {
                $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
            }
            $this->setSubscriberEmail($email);
        }
        if ($isSubscribeOwnEmail) {
            try {
                $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($this->_customerSession->getCustomerId());
                $this->setStoreId($customer->getStoreId());
                $this->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                $this->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
                $this->setCustomerId(0);
            }
        } else {
            $this->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
            $this->setCustomerId(0);
        }

        $this->setStatusChanged(true);
        try {
            $this->save();
            if ($isConfirmNeed === true
                && $isOwnSubscribes === false
            ) {
                $this->sendConfirmationRequestEmail();
            } else {
                $this->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();
            }
            return $this->getStatus();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```